# A kind of surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is there a way* to prove that a Bonnet Surface $S$ in isothermal coordinates in $R^3$ with mean curvature ($H$) and Gaussian curvature ($K$) both non-constant and where $(H^2-K)=c$, (with c positive constant), must have negative Gaussian curvature?

Thanks in advance for any help!
Alex

- *so do not use formulas $A$, $B$ and $P$ in the paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102650843

Comment: Are you omitting some hypotheses?  Do you want the surface to be complete or compact?  Also, do you really want it to be a Bonnet surface (which is more conditions than just $H^2-K$ being a positive constant)?

Comment: Dead prof. Bryant, Thanks you for your answer. I know, but of course I may be wrong, that if a surface is without umbilical points and have $H^2-K$ that is positive, than is a Bonnet's surface. I'm doing it wrong? I have read, more time ago, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102650843  and I found that if I want that S doesn't have umbilical points and $H^2-K=c$ with c  positive constant, and H and K both not constant, than using (10), I have $-2*K*c=|gradH|^2$, than $K$ is negative. I want find another way to get to this result

Comment: ...for "for this result", I mean what I found, that $k$ must be negative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to prove that any surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ that has both $H$ and $K$ nonconstant but $H^2-K=c^2$ for some constant $c>0$ must have $K$ be negative.  In fact, one cannot conclude anything about the sign of $K$ from only these hypotheses, beyond the fact that $K\ge -c^2$.

In fact, it's not difficult to show, using the Cartan-Kähler Theorem, that there exist plenty of such surfaces with $K$ positive.  I can supply the details if you want.

Whether adding the condition that the surface be a Bonnet surface could force $K$ to be negative is another question.  I think that is probably not the case, but I'd have to work it out to be sure.

**Added after the question was changed:** There are *no* Bonnet surfaces $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ with the property that $H$ is nonconstant while $H^2-K>0$ is constant (where 'Bonnet surface' means that there is a nontrivial isometric deformation of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that preserves the mean curvature $H$).  Thus, the OP's question is not sensible.

A proof that such surfaces do not exist can be got by simply differentiating the equation $H^2-K = r^2$ (where $r>0$ is a constant) several times and combining it with the three equations that follow from requiring that the surface admit a nontrvial $1$-parameter family of isometric embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^3$, all with the same *nonconstant* mean curvature function $H$.

A careful analysis shows that this overdetermined system is incompatible, even locally.  The full analysis is too long to input here.  However, you can find a discussion of this in Section 7.2 of [my introductory lectures on exterior differential systems](https://services.math.duke.edu/~bryant/MSRI_Lectures.pdf).  If you follow those notes to the discussion on page 50, what this amounts to is seeking a solution to the ODE system on $\mathbb{R}^5$ near the bottom of that page that also satisfies $r_1=0$ while $H_1\not=0$ and $H$ and $r$ are nonzero.  Since there are no such solutions, there are no such surfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for the unswer..can you supply the details?(It's very interesting). If I add that S doesn't have umbilical points?

Comment: Because if I add that S doesn't have umbilical points and use the formula for "P" in (10) of the article which I referred above, I think it proves something like $-2*c*k=|gradH|^2$, where $c$ is $(H^2-k)$

Comment: @AlexanderPigazzini:  The assumption $H^2-K>0$ already implies that $S$ has no umbilical points.  This is because $H^2-K = (\kappa_1-\kappa_2)^2/4$, where $\kappa_i$ are the principal curvatures.  The formula for $P$ in (10) of the article that you are citing doesn't help because $A$ and $B$ in the equation above it generally are not zero, so there's no reason to believe that $P$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you prof. Bryant, yes you are right if $H^2-K>0$ already implies that S has no umbilical points, I was confused..sorry!

Comment: For the issue of the cited paper, I thought that by the Theorem 1 we have that: “Let $S$ be a piece of an oriented surface in $R^3$ such that it has no umbilic points. Then, $S$ admits a non-trivial isometric deformation preserving the mean curvature function (i.e. is a Bonnet surface) if and only if one of the following conditions holds….ect”
The condition are $A=B=0$, or $P=\Delta \alpha=0$.

Comment: Reading the paper is that $A=B=0$ if and only if  $P=\Delta \alpha=0$.
The formula (9) holds at non-umbilic points of any surface in $R^3$.
Then if  I have that $S$ has $(H^2-K)=c$ with c postive constant and if $S$ is a Bonnet surface, via the Theorem 1, I must have $A=B=0$ or $P=\Delta \alpha=0$. Now if I hypothesize that $A=B=0$, this implies $P=0$, than from (10) I get $-2*c*k=|gradH|^2$.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: thank you prof. I read your "Added after the question was changed" and I will read as soon as possible your "my introductory lectures on exterior differential systems"...Thanks again, Alex

Comment: Dear prof. Bryant, I have difficulty to understanding why the system becomes inconsistent...can you give me a hint, please?

Comment: @AlexanderPigazzini:  Unfortunately, I am rather busy today, so I don't have time to help right now.  I'll try to get to it by tomorrow.

Comment: is there a name for this class of surfaces? (ie $H^2-K=c^2$, with $c>0$ constant and $H$ nonconstant)